# add entity to the end of bindinglist cause updating previous entities

Tags: c#, bindinglist

I read my records from database and restore in binding list. now I want to add new entitys to my bindinglist but It dosent work.
when I add a first entity There is no problem. after that for each entity I insert, my previous entitys change to last entity. 
I ts like that every entitys are point to one entity, and when I add new entity every entities change and update to new value. 
here is my code.

```
                My_Entity _Entity;
                BindingList<My_Entity> List;
                 //====================================
                List = businessLogic.SelectAll();//fill list
                 //===============================================
                _Entity = new My_Entity();
                _Entity = get_data(); //fill entity here
                businessLogic.Entity = _Entity;
                if (businessLogic.SendToInsert())
                {
                    List.Add(_Entity);

                }
```

where is the problem ?

Comment: What's the code in get_data()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks every body.
The Entity in Get_Data() Method. didnt be new in each time I call it. I new that entity and the problem is solved .

Answer (score 0):

try with below settings

```
BindingList<My_Entity> List ;
List.AllowNew = true;
List.AllowEdit = true;
List.AllowRemove = true;
```

Comment: Thank for your reply. I test it . it dosent work . And I still have the problem.